csv parser is interpreting the commas inside the json array as column separators
How do I define an array in a csv file so it is not parsed as extra columns?
csv parser is interpreting the commas inside the json array as column separators here is how my array is structured
trigger,tr_pipeline,pipelines.parameters.p_pbi_reports_to_refresh,"[{""workspaceId"": ""workspaceId1"", ""datasetId"": ""datasetId1""}, {""workspaceId"": ""workspaceId2"", ""datasetId"": ""datasetId2""}]"

the config csv file consists of adf objects for deployment,
the format is type,name,path,value
when i deploy the csv i get an error Missing type name after '['

Do you want to generate the file as above from ADF? Or read the above existing file using ADF? And what is your expected output should look like?

No, this is just a config-devl.csv file that lives in the deployment of my datafactory repo. This contains all the adf objects that will be deployed. The expected output is to populate a trigger in adf based on the value i provide in the config file. Which is an array of power bi reports to be refresh based on workspace id and dataset id

Did you tried to change the column delimiter in the ADF?

Is the ADF already created? if not how are you deploying the ADF?

try using double quotes around the JSON string and escaping each double quote inside it. For your example, it would look like this:
trigger,tr_pipeline,pipelines.parameters.p_pbi_reports_to_refresh,"""[{""workspaceId"": ""workspaceId1"", ""datasetId"": ""datasetId1""}, {""workspaceId"": ""workspaceId2"", ""datasetId"": ""datasetId2""}]"""

I get an unexpected token ‘workspaceId”: “workspaceId1”, “datasetId”: “datasetId1”}]”’ in expression or statement. Please take a look at the quotes in my reply.

Yes add is already created and add has 1 parameter of type array.

can you add images of your ADF pipeline and dataset.

Below are possible ways you can read the your config-devl.csv.

Use different delimiter which you are not using anywhere in csv file.

example:
trigger|tr_pipeline|pipelines.parameters.p_pbi_reports_to_refresh|"[{""workspaceId"": ""workspaceId1"", ""datasetId"": ""datasetId1""}, {""workspaceId"": ""workspaceId2"", ""datasetId"": ""datasetId2""}]"

Give delimiter as |.

Escape the  , character in your array.

trigger,tr_pipeline,pipelines.parameters.p_pbi_reports_to_refresh,[{""workspaceId"": ""workspaceId1""\, ""datasetId"": ""datasetId1""}\, {""workspaceId"": ""workspaceId2""\, ""datasetId"": ""datasetId2""}]

You also set the configuration Quote character as empty and Escape character as \ while reading this file.
